# XSD 1.1: Restrict use of an element to another attribute having a certain substring

Tags: xml, if-statement, xsd, attributes, dependencies

For another of card-game I am supposed to design an element that is only being used when an attribute in an earlier place has any value, that contain the substring "Count" as seen in this example:

```
    <card>
        <type condition="numberCount" until="3">Draw</type>
        <text>Draw one card for any new card on the field with a value not being 2 in the next 3 upcoming rounds.</text>
        <count>-2</count>
    </card>
```

My question is: How do I make the use of the element "count" dependent on the attribute "condition" in the element "type" having the word "Count" inside its value? I already tried to solve it by using the following assert but it seems to have a wrong expression (at least it's not compiling): `<xs:assert test="if (type/@condition contains('Count')) then (count) else not(count)"/>`

So how do I express the following if-statement in an xml scheme:

`if (type.condition.contains('Count') then required(count) else don't use(count))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could test whether the `type/@condition` value contains the word `Count` inside of a predicate, and then if it does whether or not the `count` element exists, otherwise return `true()`.

```
<xs:assert test="if (type/@condition[contains(., 'Count')]) 
                 then exists(count)
                 else not(count)"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I just had to edit the assert a little bit since "count" should not be a used variable if there is no "condition". So what I ended up with was:

`<xs:assert test="if (type/@condition[contains(., 'Count')]) then exists(count) else not(count)"/>`